# Laravel, Eloquent Many to Many with Many To Many in Pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

How is the best way to represent this in Eloquent Models:

jobs  -- **ManyToMany** --  (providers -- **ManyToMany**-- services)

Tables:

```
| providers | services  |services_providers | jobs      | jobs_services_providers
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id        | id        | id                | id        | id                        |
|           |           | providers_id      |           | services_providers_id     |
|           |           | services_id       |           | job_id                    |
|           |           | price             |           | price                     |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Laravel official documentation which is available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) your models should look like

**Model Jobs**

```
class Jobs extends Model {    
    public function providers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Providers');
    }    
}
```

**Model Providers**

```
class Providers extends Model {
    public function jobs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Jobs');
    }
    public function services(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Services');
    }
}
```

**Model Services**

```
class Services extends Model {    
    public function providers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Providers');
    }    
}
```

If you using pivot tables then you can define pivot table in model

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Providers', 'services_providers');
```

If you want to customize your fields in pivot relationship in Eloquent then use something like

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Providers', 'services_providers', 'service_id', 'provider_id');
```

For all other help you should be fine with using [LARAVEL OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many)

Hope it helps